# Kinetic theory of physics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, degrees-of-freedom

$$E = (3/2) kT$$

For average kinetic energy of a molecule gas.The constant $k$ does not depend on the type of molecule. Can this result be true for both hydrogen and chlorine?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. We expect here some degree of effort from your part in informing yourself. Did you check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas)? If you did, please improve your question with a more specific query.

Comment: I would think that all *constants* would not depend on anything...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP shows no research efforts.

Comment: Yes, it can be true. Find a copy of *Thermodynamics* by Sears.  Reading that should convince you. If it doesn't, then clearly write your difficulties and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2):

For both hydrogen and chlorine E = 3/2 kT is only true at very low temperatures since they are diatomic gases. In general you get a contribution of 1/2 kT to the energy for every **quadratic degree of freedom**. For a monatomic gas that is 3 translational degrees of freedom, hence 3*1/2 kT.
For a diatomic gas there are in addition 2 rotational, 1 vibrational mode. The vibrational one counts twice in the harmonic oscillator approximation, therefore 7/2 kT

In practice you observe 5/2 kT at room temperature for most gases, since there isn't enough energy to excite the vibrational modes. For a detailed description of the regimes a more complicated model is needed.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Diatomic_gases